# 301 FROM URL with parameters TO URL with parameters

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I cannot find a case with both sides (src and target) with parameters,

I need to make a 301 from:

www.example.com/test-test/test.html?subcats=Y&features_hash=V231

to

www.example.com/test-test/test.html?features_hash=18-231

Comment: I've editted my post, please help with the revised URLs

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^subcats=Y&features_hash=V(231)$
RewriteRule /test-test/test.html /test-test/test.html?features_hash=18-%1 [R=301,L]
```

Actually this can be done in one RewriteRule but this rule will be too long

Comment: It doesn't work, but maybe coz I skipped a category in the middle, so its more like www.example.com/test-1/test.html

Comment: @Caipiranha: Then edit your question and provide correct `from` and `to` URLs

Comment: I've updated my answer according to the new details you are provided

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, the target link is actually stripped from "?subcats=Y" - I've edited the original post once again. Sorry alexeevdv, would you mind updating :(?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this rule in `/test-test/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+(.*?/test\.html\?subcats=Y&features_hash)=V(\d+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1=18-%2 [R=301,L]
```